# SpringSource: Grails plugins

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

More often when I install a plugin, doesn't recognize it.
For example using Joda Time, I have a variable LocalDateTime date (i'm importing joda library) and eclipse says unable to resolve class LocalDateTime, though the application works.
Or I have installed the grails icepush plugin but after the installation taglib files were missing.

It's a SpringSource problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, chances are the eclipse toolset is still behind the competition. As mentioned by @Burt, you can get the STS from SpringSource directly or  you can get IntelliJ IDEA which also has a very good clean interface to Grails applications. The latest 9.0.3 works very well with large, complex Grails applications, and seems to have a very advanced intellisense (autocomplete) capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) which is Eclipse bundled with a suite of plugins. It has great support for Groovy and Grails. 2.5.0 was recently released and it has a plugin wizard for installing, updating, and uninstalling plugins, although it supports plugins installed from the commandline too. I find I sometimes need to manually refresh it but that's simple - just right-click on the project and select Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies.

After installing you'll need to add support for Groovy and Grails - that's available from the Dashboard.

Download from http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake. I said eclipse but actually I'm already using SpringSource 2.3.3.M2. so the problem is with Spring